# AWS Lambda with .Net core - Enabling Injection for IOptions?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda

I've created an empty AWS Lambda project with .net CORE :

[image]

Which basically all it yields is a .net core empty lambda function project :

[image]

But as it is now - it doesn't support Injection (DI) , since there is no `startup` file etc ...So basically it is ia .net core project without all its benefits.

[**However** ,  Tony wrote about it: 
`Add .NET Core DI and Config Goodness to AWS Lambda Functions`"](https://blog.tonysneed.com/2018/12/16/add-net-core-di-and-config-goodness-to-aws-lambda-functions/) :

Basically what he did is to manually make the project support DI.

So I've created a `ConfigurationService` class :

**ConfigureServices.cs**

```
 public interface IConfigurationService
    {
        IConfiguration GetConfiguration();
    }

    public class ConfigurationService : IConfigurationService
    {
        public IConfiguration GetConfiguration()
        {
            return new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();
        }
    }
```

And then used it in the code , as in a regular way .

So here is the same function as above returning a key from appSettigs  , PLUS (!!!) Dependency Injection:

**Function.cs**

```
public class Function
    {
        public Function()
        {
            /*MANUALLY MAKING OUR PROJECT TO SUPPORT DI*/
            var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
            ConfigureServices(serviceCollection);
            var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
            ConfigService = serviceProvider.GetService<IConfigurationService>();
        }

        public IConfigurationService ConfigService { get; }

        private void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
        {
            serviceCollection.AddOptions();
            serviceCollection.AddTransient<IConfigurationService, ConfigurationService>();

        }


        public string FunctionHandler(string input, ILambdaContext context)
        {
            var res = ConfigService.GetConfiguration()["Message"];
            return res;
        }
    }
```

It does work :

[image]

(Here is the appsetting.json file BTW) :

**appsettings.json**

```
{
    "Message": "Hello"
}
```

It also work when I Inject  `IConfigurationService` to other class'es constructor.

So where is the problem?

I want to use the type safe access to the appsettings.json using `IOptions`.
— So I've created a corresponding file:

**AppSettings.cs**

```
 public class AppSettings
    {
        public string Message  { get; set; }
    }
```

And now I need to `configure` it  , but look what happens:

[image]

It first invokes the `ConfigureServices` method in line #16 , then It `Configure` the `AppSettings` at line #27 , and then it crashes(!) at line #27  becuase `ConfigService` is `null`. 
Why is it null ? Because it is only assigned in line #18

**Question**

What should I do in order for the code to support `Configure<Appsettings>` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do not really need `IOptions` in this scenario and can configure the dependencies as needed

For example review the following

```
public class Function {
    public static Func<IServiceProvider> ConfigureServices = () => {
        var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
        
        serviceCollection.AddOptions(); //OPTIONAL
        
        //...add additional services as needed
        
        //building configuration
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build();
        
        //Get strongly typed setting from appsettings binding to object graph
        var settings = configuration.Get<AppSettings>();
        // adding to service collection so that it can be resolved/injected as needed.
        serviceCollection.AddSingleton(settings);
        
        return serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
    };

    static IServiceProvider services;
    
    static Function() { //Static ctor invokes once.
        services = ConfigureServices();
    }

    public string FunctionHandler(string input, ILambdaContext context) {
        //...
    
        var settings =  services.GetRequiredService<AppSettings>();
        var message = settings.Message;
        return message;
    }
}
```

A one time setup of static service provider is configured with the desired settings added to the provider as a strongly typed model which can be resolved and injected as needed.

Comment: After doing `var settings = configuration.Get<AppSettings>();

        serviceCollection.AddSingleton(settings);` - this means that I can inject it to CTOR ? How ? it doesn't have an interface.......

Comment: @RoyiNamir classes can also be injected. While most would suggest against it, that is usually for services that provide some functionality. This class is a simple POCO used to store settings and really has no need for an abstraction.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It does work , but However - please notice that now , I can't use IConfigurationServices for Injection in other places. It is possible to Use in your sample , an injected IConfiguration ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir I am aware. That was intentional. You really should not be passing around and injecting `IConfiguration`. Should really be confined to the composition root.

Comment: Wow thanks for the enlightenment. Make sense now :-) thank you ! Too bad that AWS didnt use the goodness for DI in the first place .

Comment: @RoyiNamir I guess they did not want to couple to 3rd party dependencies. However DI in .net core is modularised enough to allow it to be used without much complications / conflicts.

Comment: For Iconfiguration , I agree , it should be done only in root.  But how can we get access to IHostingenvironment ? this line `_hostingEnvironment = _serviceProvider.GetService<IHostingEnvironment>();` - returns null  , and I do want it to be injectiable

Comment: @RoyiNamir you would need to add it to the service collection so that is is available  in the provider. You have to add everything manually as you take the role of the framework that does it for you automatically in default asp.net core

Comment: We tried ....  `_serviceCollection.AddTransient<IHostingEnvironment >();` , but it doesnt work

Comment: update we've managed to it via : `_serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IHostingEnvironment >(new HostingEnvironment());`....... hope it's the right way

Comment: @RoyiNamir Yes, but you would need to populate some of the `HostingEnvironment` properties of the class as they are not populated by default. https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Hosting/Hosting/src/Internal/HostingEnvironment.cs

Comment: Royi Namir: 

To inject the type as a constructor, you'd just do the following:

serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IEnterpriseLoggingRepository, EnterpriseLoggingRepository>(provider => new EnterpriseLoggingRepository(loggerConfiguration));